# The StandardPrice field appears in the PriceBookEntry object, but I can't include it in a query

Tags: pricebookentry, standard-field

This query works:

`select name, UnitPrice, ProductCode, UseStandardPrice from PriceBookEntry`

But this query fails with the complaint "No such column StandardPrice":

`select name, UnitPrice, ProductCode, StandardPrice, UseStandardPrice from PriceBookEntry`

StandardPrice is a standard field.  Not one we have added.

For whatever clue it may be, I used Navatar's lister of object fields, and StandardPrice doesn't appear:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090fnIAA

Below I'm attempting to insert a picture that shows the StandardPrice field in my PriceBookEntry description.

[image: See the StandardPrice field?]

Comment: I don't see any standardprice as a standard field on pricebookentry object. Can you verify once? It will be the unitprice on pricebookentry

Comment: Very interesting, Anurag.  When I use the tool I mention above, that shows the "physical" fields, indeed it is UnitPrice.  I don't know what this means.

Comment: I just noticed there's UnitPrice as well as StandardPrice.  I was focusing on StandardPrice, but I'm sure UnitPrice was always there.  So, why don't you see StandardPrice?  There's no way we could have locally added a field to the "Standard Fields" is there?

Comment: It's apparently a "convenience" field. You can't readily get to it from the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm), so apparently you can't get it from Apex code either. You could always write a query like "SELECT UnitPrice, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new) AND Pricebook2.IsStandard = TRUE" or something like that. I don't see a way to get at the price directly.